# Откуда в блоке появилось коричневое пятно?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пятно распологается слева напротив строки Your Comment. И образовалось это пятно именно после появления данной строки. Почему так произошло?

```css
.project {
    height: 700px;
    width: 1360px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.title-project {
    color: #1d1d1d;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
.let {
    color: #818181;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
.lett {
    color: #818181;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    margin-top: -13px;
}
.input1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left: 340px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.input2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
input[type="text"] {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #787878;
    outline: none;
}
input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #787878;
}
input [type="text"]::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #787878;
}
.input3 {
    width: 647px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left: 340px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.input4 {
    width: 647px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: 320px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: left top;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #fff;
    color: #787878;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.input5 {
    width: 170px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #10c9c3;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-left: 582px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: 1 px solid #10c9c3;
}
```

```html
<div class="project">
<h3 class="title-project">Need a Project?</h3>
<p class="let">Let us know what you're looking for in an agency. We'll take a look and see </p>
<p class="lett">if this could be the start of something beautiful.</p>
<input class="input1" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Your Name">
<input class="input2" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Your Email">
<br>
<input class="input3" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Your Title">
<br>
<li><textarea class="input4"  placeholder="Your Comment"></textarea></li>
<br>
<form>
    <input class="input5" type="button" value="SEND MESSAGE"> 
</form>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы про кружок слева внизу? Самый стандартный маркер списка, как и у любого другого тега `<li>`.

Comment: Вопрос, что здесь вообще делает тег li. Есть какое-то рациональное объяснение?

Comment: Для создания строки Your Comment. Из-за необходимых размеров строки ввода, здесь не подошёл тег input, так как в этом случае Your Comment находился бы посередине строки.

Comment: @humster_spb так вон в разметке нарисовано `<li><textarea class="input4"  placeholder="Your Comment"></textarea></li>` :)

Comment: @СергейМишин, я вижу, что там нарисовано. Я спрашиваю - зачем? wtf?? :)

Comment: @humster_spb ааа) неопытность, очевидно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если обратить внимание на Ваш html код, то можно заметить данную строчку:

```
<li><textarea class="input4"  placeholder="Your Comment"></textarea></li>
```

Вы `textarea` поместили внутрь маркерованного элемента списка! Удалите тег `<li>` и всё заработает